# Loop for numbering weeks of the year

Tags: php, loops, datetime

Hi I need to create a php loop where I have "2015-05-22" as week1 then weeks 2, 3 and 4 are all created automatically from this date.
I know I can get the week number by using which I may be better off using but I still need that to be broken down into 4 weekly segments:

```
$startdate = "2015-05-22";
echo "Week: ".date("W", strtotime($startdate));
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just echo out 1, 2, 3, etc in a loop

Comment: Just change months to weeks and you have your date loop

Comment: Please re-phrase your question, it really does not make much sense. Best thing I can come up with is store the number of the week you want to start with then minus that number from the next week? Also look into the `DateTime` object

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2099808/4960774